# How do you prevent debug messages from displaying?

Tags: php, cakephp

When I set my debug mode to Production...and a recoverable error occurs within the code, CakePHP will output the error details in the UI.  How do I prevent this from displaying?

...debug config setting:

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

...sample code to cause an error (within a controller action):

```
 $myError = $something['NullExceptionGoes']['HERE'];
```

...this causes a cake-debug block to be added to the view (just below the beginning body tag):

error details will be output...i do not want users to see this info...i want to prevent this block from being displayed

```
<pre class="cake-debug">
    <a onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr1-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr1-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');" href="javascript:void(0);"><b>Notice</b> (8)</a>
    : Undefined variable: something [<b>APP/controllers/home_controller.php</b>, line <b>12</b>]
    <div style="display: none;" class="cake-stack-trace" id="cakeErr1-trace">
        <a onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr1-code').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr1-code').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')" href="javascript:void(0);">Code</a> | <a onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr1-context').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr1-context').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')" href="javascript:void(0);">Context</a><div style="display: none;" class="cake-code-dump" id="cakeErr1-code"><pre><code><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$this-&gt;set('title_for_layout',&nbsp;$title_for_layout);</span></code>
        <code><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span></code>
        <span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$myvar&nbsp;=&nbsp;$something['nullexceptiongoeshere']['hello'];</span></code></span></pre></div>
        <pre style="display: none;" class="cake-context" id="cakeErr1-context">$title_for_layout    =   "page title"</pre>
        <pre class="stack-trace">HomeController::index() - APP/controllers/home_controller.php, line 12
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83</pre>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: @pleasedontbelong ...sorry about that...i just cleaned up my old questions...thanks for the reminder

Comment: Did you change the `Configure::write('debug', 0);` in `core.php`? Do you have `Configure::write('debug');` anywhere else in your app?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overriding debug output in your controller method.

Verify that:

```
Configure::write('debug', x);
```

is not in your controller as well (where x = 1 or 2).